# LXD / Container / Apache2 / Iptables - Unable to load external sources in website

Tags: apache, containers, iptables, lxc, lxd

I have a container setup with LXD running several wordpress webpages (apache2)
All is working fine.

I added portforwarding by:

```
lxc config device add CONTAINER lxd_proxy_port80 proxy listen=tcp:0.0.0.0:80 connect=tcp:INTERNALIP:80
```

…and same for port 443. Thats all working correctly.

Unfortunately I cannot see originating IP’s in my apache2 logs (var/log/apache2/access.log) but only see the local IP.
By using iptables I wanted to change this. I did:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d LOCALIP --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d LOCALIP --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

and deleting my proxy device with

```
lxc config device remove CONTAINER lxd_proxy_port80
lxc config device remove CONTAINER lxd_proxy_port443
```

I can actually access files on my server correctly and I also see now my external IP in the apache2 access logs.

However, wordpress does not reach update-servers anymore (external) and seems to have problems reaching the outside world and one of my wordpress pages cannot access the index.php file anymore (it hangs loading). I suppose the latter effect is due to some external content not being loaded correctly.

Could you help me understand what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This conversation answers the questions:
https://discuss.linuxcontainers.org/t/iptables-apache-in-lxd-container/6143
A good video on this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1p-fbS_OYTg

My solution did end up working by adding a -d MYIP/32 in the iptables rule to only make it apply for incoming traffic.